# Opportunities for Graduate Economics Students

Tags: soft-question

What internship opportunities, Fellowships, External Research Grants (Preferably Paid) are specifically catered towards PhD students in Economics? To name a few I know of Amazon, Microsoft, Uber, and United Nations (Unpaid or very modest stipend unfortunately).

Generally, departments do a better job about informing students of grants, fellowships, so I would like internships to be the sole of focus of this question, but you are welcome to post about other opportunities that are not institution specific.

Comment: Many [economic consulting firms](https://firsthand.co/best-companies-to-work-for/consulting/best-firms-in-each-practice-area/economic-consulting) do offer summer internship programs to PhDs. Central banks and government statistical agencies also have similar positions.